# Is it possible embed PDF to jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, embed

Is it possible to embed a "static" file or dynamically generated PDF in jQuery UI dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Not consistently as everybody has the default behavior set differently. The only reliable way would be to generate HTML or an image to put in the dialog, even with an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Tried an [IFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)? :)